# Will most USB PS2-like controllers work on PS3?

Tags: controllers

I have to buy a wired PS3 controller for my friend, but I can only find "Windows supported" controllers. Will it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "PS2-like"?

Comment: looks like a PS2 controller. Or a PS3 controller...

Comment: Seeing how I seriously doubt that "Windows supported" means automatic PS3 support, I'm pretty sure this question cannot be answered without talking about a more specific control model. Maybe you could add a link to a product page for a controller you would like to purchase?

Comment: Why can't you use a normal PS3 controller?  If you want, you can always have it plugged in with its recharging cord.  You can even get USB extenders to make the cord stretch further.

Comment: @bwarner - because I don't live in your country and a normal PS3 and very expensive.

Comment: why vote down? Someone perfectly answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some PS2-like controllers have been found to work with the PS3 (mostly the Logitech ones) but there is no guarantee that any certain third party controller would work with the PS3 unless it is specifically stated to have PS3 support.

Answer (score -1):

Most USB controllers work on PS3.

Comment: A source to pack that up would be nice.